# How do I calculate the average of a variable between two date ranges using a loop or apply function?

Tags: r, loops, date, average, apply

I am trying to calculate the mean of the device count between a date range (for example, from July 21 to July 28th).

So this is what my data looks like, for example:

```
# A tibble: 580,742 x 14
   country_region_~ country_region sub_region_1 sub_region_2 census_fips_code date      
   <chr>            <chr>          <chr>        <chr>        <chr>            <date>    
 1 US               United States  NA           NA           NA               2020-02-15
 2 US               United States  NA           NA           NA               2020-02-16
 3 US               United States  NA           NA           NA               2020-02-17
 4 US               United States  NA           NA           NA               2020-02-18
 5 US               United States  NA           NA           NA               2020-02-19
 6 US               United States  NA           NA           NA               2020-02-20
 7 US               United States  NA           NA           NA               2020-02-21
 8 US               United States  NA           NA           NA               2020-02-22
 9 US               United States  NA           NA           NA               2020-02-23
10 US               United States  NA           NA           NA               2020-02-24
# ... with 580,732 more rows, and 8 more variables:
#   retail_and_recreation_percent_change_from_baseline <dbl>,
#   grocery_and_pharmacy_percent_change_from_baseline <dbl>,
#   parks_percent_change_from_baseline <dbl>,
#   transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline <dbl>,
#   workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline <dbl>,
#   residential_percent_change_from_baseline <dbl>, date2 <date>, date3 <date>
```

And I was able to manually calculate averages between date ranges with this code:

```
library(dplyr)
retailavg <- google.mobility %>% 
    mutate(weekrange = date >= "2020-02-15" & date <= "2020-02-21") %>% 
    filter(weekrange) %>% 
    group_by(sub_region_2) %>% 
    summarise(avgretail = mean(retail_and_recreation_percent_change_from_baseline))
```

Loops are my worst nightmare, but if there is any way a loop/apply can be created so I don't have to do each date range manually, it would definitely help! I'm an absolute beginner, so any advice would help!

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example using dput() function?

Comment: `date >= "2020-02-15"` is a *string* comparison not a (number-like) comparison of dates. In this format it is close-enough, but to be sure ... `date >= as.Date("2020-02-15")` is better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if all of your summary periods will be aligned on the same day-of-week ("week-aligned") or not, so I've answered both. Frankly, the non-week-aligned answer can be used even if everything is perfectly week-aligned, so go with that if you think you'll need flexibility.

### Week-aligned date ranges

If it is always "by-week" (whatever day they are aligned on), then you can simply calculate the week number and group by that variable.

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(week = as.integer(date - as.Date("2020-02-15")) %/% 7) %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  summarize(
    startdate = min(date), enddate = max(date),
    avgval = mean(val)
  )
# # A tibble: 53 x 4
#     week startdate  enddate    avgval
#    <dbl> <date>     <date>      <dbl>
#  1    -7 2020-01-01 2020-01-03  0.525
#  2    -6 2020-01-04 2020-01-10  0.568
#  3    -5 2020-01-11 2020-01-17  0.460
#  4    -4 2020-01-18 2020-01-24  0.657
#  5    -3 2020-01-25 2020-01-31  0.468
#  6    -2 2020-02-01 2020-02-07  0.494
#  7    -1 2020-02-08 2020-02-14  0.444
#  8     0 2020-02-15 2020-02-20  0.391
#  9     1 2020-02-22 2020-02-28  0.472
# 10     2 2020-02-29 2020-03-06  0.502
# # ... with 43 more rows
```

The trick in that one is that we align the week rollover on an arbitrary date (your `"2020-02-15"` here), so that that day of the week and every repeat of that day through the year will represent the beginning of each window. Here's what a sample of that looks like:

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(week = as.integer(date - as.Date("2020-02-15")) %/% 7) %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  filter(week == 0 | (week == -1 & row_number() == n()) | (week == 1 & row_number() == 1))
# # A tibble: 17 x 3
# # Groups:   week [3]
#    date          val  week
#    <date>      <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 2020-02-14 0.814     -1
#  2 2020-02-15 0.130      0
#  3 2020-02-15 0.811      0
#  4 2020-02-15 0.0691     0
#  5 2020-02-16 0.476      0
#  6 2020-02-16 0.537      0
#  7 2020-02-16 0.207      0
#  8 2020-02-18 0.210      0
#  9 2020-02-18 0.521      0
# 10 2020-02-18 0.998      0
# 11 2020-02-18 0.946      0
# 12 2020-02-18 0.309      0
# 13 2020-02-18 0.440      0
# 14 2020-02-18 0.0271     0
# 15 2020-02-20 0.148      0
# 16 2020-02-20 0.0295     0
# 17 2020-02-22 0.972      1
```

Here you can see that the `0` group contains your range of `"2020-02-15"` through `"2020-02-21"` (even if there's no `02-21` in this random data). The actual numbers -1, 0, 1 here are completely arbitrary, we just use them for their grouping property.

### Not week-aligned

This can be done without a loop using a "non-equi" or "range" join. Unfortunately, `dplyr` does not support it natively (though indirectly it supports it with `dbplyr::sql_on`), but here are a few alternatives: `data.table`, `sqldf`, and `fuzzyjoin` (with `dplyr`):

```r
library(data.table)
datDT <- as.data.table(dat)
ranges <- data.table(
  date    = as.Date(c("2020-02-15", "2020-03-01", "2020-09-14")),
  enddate = as.Date(c("2020-02-21", "2020-03-05", "2020-09-30"))
)
ranges
#          date    enddate
# 1: 2020-02-15 2020-02-21
# 2: 2020-03-01 2020-03-05
# 3: 2020-09-14 2020-09-30
datDT[ranges, on = .(date >= date, date <= enddate)] %>%
  .[, .(enddate = max(date), avgval = mean(val)), by = .(date)]
#          date    enddate      avgval
# 1: 2020-02-15 2020-02-15 0.390515534
# 2: 2020-03-01 2020-03-01 0.533702911
# 3: 2020-09-14 2020-09-14 0.479576581
```

(The first row of ranges was intentionally the same as above, showing the same mean value of `0.391`.) This effects a left-join on `ranges`; if `dplyr` supported non-equi joins, then it would be `left_join(ranges, dat, ...)`. (In fact, look at the `fuzzyjoin` option towards the bottom of this answer.)

Similarly,

```r
# library(sqldf)
sqldf::sqldf("
  select r.date, r.enddate, avg(val) as avgval
  from ranges r
    left join dat d on r.date <= d.date and r.enddate >= d.date
  group by r.date")
#         date    enddate      avgval
# 1 2020-02-15 2020-02-21 0.390515534
# 2 2020-03-01 2020-03-05 0.533702911
# 3 2020-09-14 2020-09-30 0.479576581
```

Lastly, you can use `fuzzyjoin`:

```r
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(
  ranges, dat, by = c("date" = "date", "enddate" = "date"),
  match_fun = list(`<=`, `>=`)) %>%
  group_by(date = date.x) %>%
  summarize(enddate = max(enddate), dateavgval = mean(val))
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   date       enddate    dateavgval
#   <date>     <date>          <dbl>
# 1 2020-02-15 2020-02-21      0.391
# 2 2020-03-01 2020-03-05      0.534
# 3 2020-09-14 2020-09-30      0.480
```

---

Data:

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date("2020-01-01") + sample(365, size = 1000, replace = TRUE) - 1,
  val = runif(1000)
)
dat <- dat[order(dat$date),]
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 1000 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ date: Date, format: "2020-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2020-01-02" "2020-01-02" ...
#  $ val : num  0.517 0.184 0.255 0.845 0.839 ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?